# Type Tool selection popup menu does not bring out

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Just installed the Adobe Illustrator CS5 (never used it before, only Photoshop) and wondering why any of tool menus does not bring out by right mouse click as it is in Photoshop. I've tried all ways I know like keyboard shortcut <kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL+T</kbd> for the tool but popup menu does not brings out.

I imagine that this could be cowboy problem, sorry for that I'm rally confused and googling intrawebs I was not able to found anything helpful.

This is what I'm trying to find out for Type Tool:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juts found an answer on the [Adobe Livedocs site](http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Illustrator/13.0/help.html?content=WS8599BC5C-3E44-406c-9288-C3B3BBEB5E88.html).

This feature called "Tear off hidden tools":

> Drag the pointer over the arrow at the end of the Tools panel and
>   release the mouse button.

Very simple but tricky for those who just come from Photoshop UI :)